# When does the external script imported by the loadasync function get executed?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

```js
// Asynchronously load and execute a script from a specified URL
function loadasync(url) {
var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]; // Find document <head>
var s = document.createElement("script"); // Create a <script> element
s.src = url; // Set its src attribute
head.appendChild(s); // Insert the <script> into head
}
```

**JavaScript:The Definite Guide** introduces such a function that loads external scripts asynchronously. But I have no idea when the imported script executes.As soon as the script that loads it finishes running? Or, after the load event on window happens?
Considering the purpose of the function or the reason why it is introduced, the answer is not likely the first case, and the following test case demonstrates:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function loadasync(url) {
            var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
            var s = document.createElement("script");
            s.src = url;
            head.appendChild(s);
        }("external.js"));
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>This is a test page.</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

The content in external.js:

```js
alert("external script executed, dead loop");
while(true);
```

The "h1" element renders normally without being blocked by the dead loop caused by the external script. It means that the imported external script executes at a later time, instead of as soon as the script that loads it finishes running. But when exactly?

Comment: I think you might find your answer here: https://www.igvita.com/2014/05/20/script-injected-async-scripts-considered-harmful/ . Also I believe that it depends on how your browser decides to handle it.

Comment: The external script runs as soon as it loads. It does not wait for `window.onload` or any other event.

Comment: But the loading of this script might happen after `window.onload`, you have no guarantee on this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's still executes right after it loads, the h1 is render is because the `js` file still takes time to load, while others can finish their rendering, I change your codes to make some test:

html part:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function loadasync(url) {
            var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
            var s = document.createElement("script");
            s.src = url;
            head.appendChild(s);
        }("./js/external.js"));
        window.onload = function() {
            alert("window loaded");
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>This is a test page.</h1>
    <div id="test">See the page</div>
</body>
</html>
```

external.js part:

```
alert("external script executed, dead loop");
var ele = document.getElementById("test");
alert(ele.innerText);
```

In my broswer, the alert's sequence is `external script executed, dead loop` => `See the page` => `window loaded`. 
So, when you executes the script, it add `script` tag to head and start to load it, while other parts of page keep rendering.

However, as you add something that needs to load, `window.onload` will wait until that `script` is loaded.

And we can observe from the alert sequence that the scripts execute itself right after its loaded.

Comment: Yes, i tried your code and it alerts the same sequence. Moreover, I find it that the injected script starts executing only after all the scripts in the <script> tag loading it finishes executing.
If you add a dead while loop after the onload handler, the external script will never execute and the browser hangs with nothing rendered.

Comment: I believe its because browser is single threaded, so it needs to end current job to get to next one, and the `while(true);` right after the handler will make it unable to put rest of the pages to view.